# Truncate a table on a schedule or first run of the day

Tags: php, mysql

I'm writing a time recording program for the company I work for. I'm using the a form to capture data from the user end.

I will be creating a dynamic interface for the managers to see what client currently handled by which user. To do this I will be auto submitting "User Name", "Category", "Client Name" and "Start Time" to a temporary table which will hold the data only for that day.

I want to know if there's a way to this using PHP script which will be running in timed manner to TRUNCATE the temporary table on each day. I'm using MySQL as my database software.

This not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19555712/empty-a-mysql-table-hourly) I'm asking to run a PHP in a timed manner

**UPDATE:** I think I found my own solution to this problem thank you all for the help will update this when I get it to work.

**UPDATE:** I used this method in order to do what I wanted to do [link](http://www.businesslegions.com/blog/2014/08/09/create-cron-jobs-wamp/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Empty a MySQL table hourly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19555712/empty-a-mysql-table-hourly)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need two table fields name `date_only` and `status`. Then in your code check `date_only` is today's date and user `status` is active then you extract `"User Name", "Category", "Client Name" and "Start Time"` of a specific manager.

If a manager manage how many number of users then the users status is `active` other users status are inactive

Answer (score 0):

If the server is hosted on Unix Based OS, you can settle a cron job to truncate the temp table at 12:00 am of everyday. Cron executes the scheduled commands and for Windows based OS you can use task scheduler.

More details: https://www.pantz.org/software/cron/croninfo.html

[How do I run a PHP script using windows schedule task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701861/how-do-i-run-a-php-script-using-windows-schedule-task)

Hope it helps